# Breathed deep vs. breathing deeply

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, grammaticality-in-context, subordinate-clauses

> He looked at the stone figures all around them, ***breathed*** **deep** in the chill of silence of the crypt. (*A Game of Thrones*)

I think he should have put ***breathing*** **deeply** instead of ***breathed*** **deep**, for two reasons:

- first, there is no adjective for the word ***breathe***
- second, breathe should be followed by adverb **deeply** not an adjective **deep**.

I want to know how this sentence works. How do you explain this condition?

Comment: _Deep_ functions as an adverb, and adjective, and a noun. What English dictionary did you consult to learn about the word _deep?_ _Breathe deep_  is an example of a verb-adjective combination, which are not uncommon in English. An outfielder in baseball also _plays deep._ Water can _run cold,_ but not "coldly". See the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary entry for _deep._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "deep" an adjective or adverb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/is-deep-an-adjective-or-adverb)

Comment: I check this word up and figured out that it functions as adverb, too.

Comment: What about ***breathed***, why did not  the writer use breathing instead of breathed?

Comment: Agree with P.E. Dant There are many other instances of an adjective plus noun like this in English and I'm too lazy to dig them up. /he breathed deep/ means it was only once. Oh, I just remember another one: to think long and hard.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe this is not a duplicate. The other question is about "burying something deep", where _deep_ can be understood as the result (a subject complement), hence it's easy to see why an adjective makes sense. With "breathe deep", that explanation doesn't seem to make sense. IOW, I can explain the other one, but I'm not sure how to explain this one—so they must not be duplicates! :)

Comment: @BenKovitz I'd start to explain it by suggesting a dictionary entry like **[Cambridge,](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/deep_2)** **[M-W Learners,](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/deep)** **[Macmillan,](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/deep_2)** ... etc.

Comment: The writer chose the participle instead of the -ing form because the participle _looked_ is used in the first clause. The subject of _breathed_ in the second clause is _He_ from the first clause; _He breathing_ doesn't make much sense in English.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm hoping for something, er, deeper than "A dictionary says that _deep_ is an adverb" or "M-W Learners says _breathe deep_ is OK." Not that you're suggesting that, but I don't see an explanation in any of those dictionaries. Many words serve more comfortably as adverbs in some contexts than others, and I think usually there are reasons why which are enlightening to know.

Comment: I think @Lambie's got an interesting hypothesis here: "Eddie breathed deep" suggests one deep breath; "Eddie breathed deeply" is equally compatible with one breath or many. For once I'm not cringing to see an answer posted as a comment. And it pretty well shows that this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @P. E. Dant what is the meaning of breathed here? Are the stones breathed? Do the stones breathe. How could just that happen unless it is a metaphorical expression.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo It appears to me that you've asked a hard question. It may take [a few days](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700) for a good answer, known with confidence, to emerge from discussion and debate. There's a lesson to be learned from that: English grammar is so chaotic, often even the native speakers can't explain it (at least not without a lot of thought).

Comment: @BenKovitz Sometimes the explanation is _"because we do it this way in English."_ I think that's why the usages are provided in many dictionaries with no explanation, any more than the entry for _cold_ explains "why" it's an adjective. We _breathe deep, run cold, stand straight, laugh loud._ OALD sez: "_The adverbs deep and deeply can both mean ‘a long way down or into something’. Deep can only mean this and is more common than deeply in this sense."_

Comment: @BavyanYaldo Again: it is not the stones that _breathed._ The subject of the verb _breathe_ in the second clause is _He,_ not _the stone figures._ The second clause is:  _"[He] breathed deep in the chill of silence of the crypt."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant I agree: sometimes [there is no explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41288/6700) other than a specific custom for a specific word. Ultimately, of course, language is nothing but custom. In the case of "breathe deep", though, I think something interesting is waiting to be pointed out, though of course I could easily be wrong. Sometimes there are subtle ways that one custom echoes another, which people exploit to communicate, and it can help to be clued into them. IOW, please keep thinking about this! You might hit on something.

Comment: @P. E. Dant so if the subject is He, why the writer didn't even put and after comma. To ensure someone that breathed referees to He not the stones. And i have a question relating to this case: a gang broke into a bank, tried or trying to rob it. What is the difference between these sentences? And whuch one is right **tried** or **trying**?

Comment: Sometimes in English, a writer will just not use a compound sentence: He looked at the stone figures all around them [and] breathed deep etc. OR: He looked at the stone figures all around them; he breathed deep. It's just this writer's quirk. It's acceptable in a script.

Comment: Either of these is fine: _"A gang broke into a bank **and** tried to rob it."_ ... or ... _"A gang broke into a bank, trying to rob it."_ Also, a writer could write _"A gang broke into a bank, tried to rob it."_ This would be immediately and easuily understood by any English speaker. The _Game of Thrones_ writer was not writing a grammar lesson. He was writing creatively. There is no "right" or "wrong" involved. No English speaker would take his sentence to mean that the stones were breathing. It doesn't make sense, and that's not what the sentence expresses.

Answer (score 2):

To "breathe deep" is a common idiom, meaning to *fully absorb the atmosphere or flavor of a place/event/situation*, as well as just *to take a deep breath* (for instance to calm yourself). Your example is using it in the sense of *absorb and connect with the atmosphere*. [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/breathe-deep) has some examples, e.g.

> Stand still, breathe deep and you can hear it in your deep heart's core.

> I stand on my balcony and breathe deep.

The first here is about breathing deep in the sense of absorbing and connecting with the place or situation and feeling it in your heart - it's more than just a literal deep breath.

For the English learner, there are three issues with Martin's sentence: punctuation; "breathed" vs "breathing"; and "deep" vs "deeply".

"Breathed" here is a simple past tense; it would be more standard to have "and" than a comma before it ("He looked at the stone figures all around them and breathed deep...") but this is literature so you can punctuate how you choose. Here the use of a comma indicates things happening more closely together or at the same time, while "and" might imply things happening one after another.

One difference between "breathed" and "breathing" is that "breathing" implies continuing action, while "breathed" could refer to taking a single breath; "breathing deep" might imply panting.

As to ["deep"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deep) vs ["deeply"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deeply), both are valid adverbs. English has many pairs like this where something can be an adverb with or without "ly", e.g. [quick/quickly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick). In the idiom "breathe deep", "deep" is common. In other contexts, "deeply" might be more common, e.g. "I love you deeply." But "breathed deeply" would not be wrong - just longer.

In summary it's a combination of a common idiom meaning "to absorb the atmosphere of a place", with simple past tense for completed action, and a comma for speed.

Answer (score -1):

Grammatically, you're correct, but the author here is using **breathed deep** in a poetic way. Some surrounding text is as follows:

> For a moment Eddard Stark was filled with a terrible sense of foreboding. This was his place, here in the north. He looked at the stone figures all around them, breathed deep in the chill silence of the crypt. He could feel the eyes of the dead. They were all listening, he knew. And winter was coming.

This paragraph is describing the crypt, and **the phrase "breathed deep" is describing the *stone figures***, not Eddard Stark's actions. This particular usage is **very unusual** even for a native speaker, and is done this way intentionally so, to add to the mental imagery that the author is attempting to convey. It helps to understand if you swap "breathed" for "buried", though it loses some of the unusual nuance.

As for using "deep" versus "deeply", that too is a creative choice. "Deeply" is what the reader (and typical grammar) would expect if "deeply" were in reference to Eddard Stark's actions, but by breaking out of expectations with use of "breathed" to account for their presence in the crypt, and following it with "deep", **it serves to adjust the purpose of deep/deeply from their depth in the crypt, to how they were breathed into it.**

Comment: It's poetic, yes, but grammatically the OP is _not_ correct. _Deep_ is an _adverb._ This has been covered in depth: see **[this question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7009/37009)**

Comment: Are you saying that the stone figures breathed? Or that "breathed" is a passive participle: the stone figures got breathed by something or someone else?

Comment: @BenKovitz The latter case. Something or someone "breathed" them into the crypt. It contributes to the cold, ancient imagery in a novel way.